# Convert array string in to list? ADD ALL section error

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-fragments, adapter

EQName list calling from the service
        JSONArray EQResponseArray = new JSONArray(EQSpecifCompanrison);

```
    int EQResponseSize = EQResponseArray.length();
    String[] EQName = new String[EQResponseSize];

     for(int i = 0; i< EQResponseSize; i++)
     {
       JSONObject EQResponseObject = EQResponseArray.optJSONObject(i);
       int EQ_ID = EQResponseObject.optInt("EquipmentStatusId");
       EQID[i] = EQ_ID;  
       String EQ_Name = EQResponseObject.optString("EquipmentStatusDescription");
       EQName[i] = EQ_Name; 
       int EQ_PlantID = EQResponseObject.optInt("equipmentParentStatusId");
       EQPlantID[i] = EQ_PlantID;

      }



  I have problem in AddALL section. I think problem in to convert how it will be? Planet constructer takes list items but my list have array list.
     ArrayList<Planet> planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();

      Object[] mStringArray = planetList.toArray();
      planetList.addAll(EQName);
      listAdapter = new PlanetArrayAdapter(getActivity(), planetList);
      SpecificList.setAdapter( listAdapter );
```

Comment: I mean :Convert String [] to ArrayList<String>

Comment: The answer is in one post .....
[Convert String to Array (android)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360513/convert-string-to-array-android

Comment: can you please explain me brief i didt get that

Comment: Java101 : ArrayList extends List, hence can be used where List is expected.

Comment: please take a look on this code, planetList.addAll(EQName) have got error because my EQname is string array and planetlist takes List